# Understanding replication and lack-of-fit in regression modeling

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit

Regarding regression analysis, I once heard that "Replicate at various predictor values will allow for lack-of-fit analysis". I do not understand how to get this kind of statement?

Comment: (-1) I don't believe you've quoted your source accurately.  Besides that, people will need to see more of the context in order to answer your question.

Comment: @gung I took my answer down because of the downvotes (even though I think my answers is appropiate).  Unfortunately that took away our comments.  Perhaps you should repeat your suggestions as they were good comments.

Comment: @Michael - FYI: only the OP and others in the comment thread are pinged with the '@' symbol, so gung did not see your comment unless he happens to have been reading this thread.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lack-of-fit_sum_of_squares  which probably contains an answer to the question